# convert plotly figure to image and then use this image as normal PNG

Tags: python, plotly, powerpoint

I'm trying to convert a plotly express figure to image, then use this image to save it on a power point slide. This is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
from pptx import Presentation


wide_df = px.data.medals_wide()

fig = px.bar(wide_df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input, relabelled",
             labels={"value": "count", "variable": "medal"})

# Convert the figure to a bytes object
img_bytes = pio.to_image(fig, format='png')

ppt = Presentation(
     "template.pptx"
 )

slide = ppt.slides[3]
placeholder = slide.placeholders[13]

placeholder.insert_picture(
           img_bytes
       )
```

But I'm getting the following **error** message:

```
'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Comment: Try importing `io` and passing `io.BytesIO(img_bytes)`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the content of `insert_picture` is a file, not an object. <- Don't quote me on that. However, if it is or is not, have you considered [using this package](https://pypi.org/project/plotlyPowerpoint/)? Plotly + pptx in one? (Perhaps you could even use both `pptx` and `plotlyPowerpoint`?

Comment: That worked @MarkSetchell!!! I'm curious about how did you know that, where have you look at? P.D: Just write that as an answer and I will validate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
import io

...
...
placeholder.insert_picture(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))
```

The clue was the error message that there is no `seek` attribute, which is a method that *"file-like"* objects have in Python, and `io.BytesIO()` is a way of making a bunch of data appear to come from, and behave like, a  file. Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).